# How to pass parameter from masterpage to all pages xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Masterpage which appear after I click on button.

Here is my code.

App.cs

```
public App()
 {
   // The root page of your application
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
 }
```

Login.cs

```
public void button(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   MasterDetailPage fpm = new MasterDetailPage();
   fpm.Master = new MasterPage(**test.Text**) { Title = "Main Page" }; // You have to create a Master ContentPage()
   fpm.Detail = new NavigationPage(new PageOne()); // You have to create a Detail ContenPage()
   Application.Current.MainPage = fpm;
 }
```

From login page i'm passing parameter to Masterpage (i.e.) **test.text**, I want to pass this parameter to all pages in the Mastepage, but I dont know how to do it.

MasterPage.cs

```
public MasterPage(string id)
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   BindingContext = new MasterViewModel();
 }
```

MasterViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand NavigationCommand
 {
  get
   {
     return new Command((value) =>
      {
        // COMMENT: This is just quick demo code. Please don't put this in a production app.
        var mdp = (Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage);
        var navPage = mdp.Detail as NavigationPage;
        // Hide the Master page
        mdp.IsPresented = false;
         switch(value)
          {
            case "1":
                    navPage.PushAsync(new PageOne());
                    break;
            case "2":
                    navPage.PushAsync(new PageTwo());
                    break;
          }
      });
   }
}
```

So basically what I need is after login I want to pass id to Masterpage, so all pages in Masterpage can get that id and based on id I can work on this project.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Can we just pass the `id` to ctor of `PageOne` or `PageTwo` ?

Comment: If you want to use it in all pages, why just not make it `static` in a `static class` you can use for this kind of stuff. Either that, or just create a `BaseViewModel` and every `PageViewModel` will be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [messaging center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

You send like this :

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

You receive like this :

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe :

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

Comment: where i have to unsubscribe? and this messaging center code do i have to use in masterdetail page?

Comment: You can use it wherever you want to communicate between différent view models